# Printing booleans in php

Tags: php, boolean

Is there something ready for printing Booleans in PHP (usually for debug), rather than writing: `echo ($flag ? "true" : "false")` every time?

Comment: Don't forget all PHP variables have the `$` sigil.

Comment: yeah, what @Stu said. 7 questions and no accepts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var_export($flag);
```

Comment: +1 handy if you are chasing just the `true` or `false` string :)

Answer (score 4):

```
$a = TRUE;
var_dump($a); // bool(true)
```

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

> A boolean TRUE value is converted to the string  "1". Boolean FALSE is converted to "" (the empty string).

Your current method is probably the easiest method without calling a function.

Comment: `Your current method is probably the easiest method without calling a function.` Not correct actually, see [Matthew Flaschen's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200501/printing-booleans-in-php/4200517#4200517).

Comment: @alex: `var_export` is a function ;)  and I was thinking along the lines of using that test in the middle of an `echo`.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a little function - that would save chars and typing!